# Add column with numbers based on a second column

Tags: r, dataframe, numbers, rows

Here my data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Day  ID  Event
                        100   1     1
                        100   1     1
                         99   1     1
                         97   1     1
                         87   2     1
                         86   2     1
                         85   2     1
                        965   1     2
                        964   1     2
                        960   1     2
                        959   1     2
                        709   2     2
                        708   2     2
                         12   3     2
                          9   3     2', header = TRUE)
```

What I would like to do is to create a new column which, considering the `ID` and `Event` ones,  assign for each observation a number in decreasing order based on the relative `Day` ones.

My desired output would be:

```
                        Day  ID  Event  Count

                        100   1     1     4
                        100   1     1     4
                         99   1     1     3
                         97   1     1     1

                         87   2     1     3
                         86   2     1     2
                         85   2     1     1

                        965   1     2     7      
                        964   1     2     6
                        960   1     2     2
                        959   1     2     1

                        709   2     2     2
                        708   2     2     1

                         12   3     2     4  
                          9   3     2     1
```

E.g. If you look at the first 'block' above: Day 97 = 1, Day 98 = 2, Day 99 = 3 and Day 100 = 4. We are missing Day 98 but we still need to include it in the count.

I tried the following but the output is not the one I need:

> df$Count <- ave(df$Day, df$Event, df$ID, FUN = seq_along)

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is not clear how you got those numbers.  Perhaps you need `?rank`

Comment: Hi akrun, I just updated my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID, Event) %>% 
    mutate(Count = 1+(Day-Day[n()]))
```